# Regular Expression to strip comments from Bash script

Tags: regex, bash

This is deceptively complex. I need a regular expression to strip comments from Bash shell scripts.

Bear in mind that `$#`, `${#foo}`, `string="this # string"`, `string='that # string'`, `${foo#bar}`, `${foo##baar}`, and

```
string="really complex args=$# ${applejack##"jack"} $(echo "$#, again")"; `echo this is a ${#nasty[*]} example`
```

are all valid shell expressions that should *not* be stripped.

**Edit:**
Note that:

```
# This is a comment in bash
  # But so is this
echo "foo bar" # This is also a comment
```

**Edit:**
Note that lines that might be misconstrued as comments may be tucked inside HEREDOCs but since it is multi-line I can live without handling/accounting for it:

```
cat<<EOF>>out.txt
This is just a heredoc
# This line looks like a comment, but it isn't
EOF
```

Comment: I'm beginning to feel this might not be possible with a simple regex, especially now that you added the heredoc-caveat. You might need to do some syntax parsing instead

Comment: Agree with carl, don't think this is regular. There are too many edge cases for arbitrary scripts.

Comment: It appears that on any given line, only the right-most # needs to be tested to see if it is part of a "string" or $# or ${#parameter[$expansion]}.

Comment: @JeffG - doesn't that fall down when within a heredoc?

Comment: @Chris McCauley, yes. I must concede that the HEREDOC case must be tossed out of the problem, because of its multiline nature.

Comment: You can also put comments in subshells:  `(# this is a comment <imagine a newline here since stack overflow doesn't allow newlines in comments>)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that with regular expressions.

```
echo ${baz/${foo/${foo/#bar/foo}/bar}/qux}
```

You need to match nested braces. Regular expressions can't do that, unless you're willing to consider PCREs "regular expressions", in which case it would be simpler to just write the parser in Perl.

Answer (score 4):

#### Just for fun ...

I don't believe you can do this without using/implementing a parser but it's fun seeing how far you can get without doing that.

The closest I gotten is to use a simple **regex** with **sed**. It preserves the hash bang which is a definite must but can't cope with the HEREDOC. You could go further but then it might not be fun anymore.

Sample bash script (called doit)

```
#!/bin/bash
#This
#  is a 
echo $1 #comment
```

Running that ...

```
cat doit | sed -e 's/#[^!].*$//'
#!/bin/bash


echo $1
```

But obviously there are blank lines produced which you don't want AND it doesn't handle HERE docs.

Again, not a serious suggestion but please play around with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; The blank lines are not a problem, but this would probably treat all the characters after dollar-sign in the following line as a comment an strip them: `echo "There are $# arguments"`

Comment: @JeffG Agreed. You would have to get increasingly clever with the regex and even at that, it wouldn't support the heredocs. Really you need a parser. Thanks for the question though and +1 for the entertaining distracting me from some boring work stuff.

Comment: That will not catch a line with only a hash on it, because your regex requires at least 1 char after the hash.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED: I admit it! sed won't work for the reasons given in comments - sed doesn't handle lookaheads/lookbehinds. Thanks for pointing that out!

I thought a comment in bash was a line that started with a #. If so, here's your regex:

```
^#
```

And here's the sed command that will strip them:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/^\s*#(?!!).*$//' myfile.sh
```

EDITED to factor in downvoter's comments: ie

- allow whitespace before the # using `\s*`
- exclude lines that have a `!` following the # using negative lookahead `(?!!)`

Comment: Comments can also have both whitespace and non-whitespace characters between the ^ (beginning of line) and the #, so this regex misses comments that are indented, for example, or comments tacked on to the end of a line.

Comment: That would also remove the initial `#!/bin/bash` (or equivalent)... Not good

Comment: Can the negative lookahead also protect the `$#` variable and `${#arraylength[*]}` and `${substring#removal}` cases? Also is there a way to handle the `"Hash # inside strings"` case?

Comment: @Bohemian - I thought sed lacked negative lookahead?